# Win32: Test if mouse has hovered for a second

Tags: c++, winapi, callback, mouse

I'm trying to make a function that only runs when the mouse has stayed in the same place for an increment of time without stalling the program (so no `Sleep(1000)` functions). What I tried to do was have the callback run a function in paint when the mouse moves. In that function, there would be a while loop that makes sure the mouse didn't move since the last frame and break if clicked or moved.

In the callback:

```
case WM_MOUSEMOVE:
    POINT pt;
    GetCursorPos(&pt);
    ScreenToClient(hWnd, &pt);
    iPosX = pt.x;
    iPosY = pt.y;

    if (!mouseMoved) {
        mouseMoved = true;
        period = 0;
        InvalidateRect(hWnd, 0, FALSE);
    }
    break;
```

In the Paint:

```
       if (mouseMoved && !MouseClicked) {

            test.newBit(1, 100, 0, hdc); //Draws a picture as a test

            oldx = iPosX;
            oldy = iPosY;

            period = 0;

            while (period <= 1000000 && !MouseClicked) {

                oldx = iPosX;
                oldy = iPosY;

                POINT pt;
                GetCursorPos(&pt);
                ScreenToClient(hWnd, &pt);
                iPosX = pt.x;
                iPosY = pt.y;

                if (iPosX != oldx || iPosY != oldy) {
                    mouseMoved = false;
                    period = 0;
                    break;
                }

                period++;
            }

            if (period <= 1000000) {
                period = 0;
                test.newBit(0, 0, 0, hdc); //Draws a picture as a test
                mouseMoved = false;
            }

        }
```

This generates a random flashing when you move the mouse and click. Any insight into what I'm doing wrong would be appreciated.

Comment: Oh! the reason it flashes irrationally is that the less than sign should be a greater than sign...oops

Comment: You can do it easier by setting a timer in `WM_MOUSEMOVE`: `KillTimer(); SetTimer();` and call the function from `WM_TIMER` event.

Comment: What would happen, if you ran this code on a machine, that's faster than yours? Or a machine, that's slower than yours?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The system already implements this for you. You just have to request mouse hover messages by calling [TrackMouseEvent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646265.aspx):

```
TRACKMOUSEEVENT tme = { sizeof( tme ) };
tme.dwFlags = TME_HOVER;
tme.hwndTrack = hWnd;
tme.dwHoverTime = 1000;
::TrackMouseEvent( &tme );
```

The application receives a [WM_MOUSEHOVER](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645613.aspx) message, when the cursor hovers over the client area of the window for the period of time specified in the call to `TrackMouseEvent`. Hover tracking stops, once a `WM_MOUSEHOVER` message is generated. To receive further `WM_MOUSEHOVER` messages, an application needs to re-request hover tracking (using code identical to that above).

An application can call [SystemParametersInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724947.aspx) and use `SPI_GETMOUSEHOVERTIME` to retrieve the default hover time-out.

Note that this takes the hover rectangle into account (`SPI_GETMOUSEHOVERWIDTH` and `SPI_GETMOUSEHOVERHEIGHT`). This is an area around the mouse cursor that the mouse is allowed to move inside, without resetting the hover timeout.

---

If you need a solution that only reports hovering when the mouse hasn't moved at all, you will have to implement this yourself. A solution based on a timer makes for a clean solution.

Whenever the mouse moves, we need to reset the timer. If the mouse was previously outside the window's client area, we also have to re-request `WM_MOUSELEAVE` messages. This is necessary so that the timer can be canceled, whenever the mouse leaves the client area:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc( HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam ) {
    enum TimerId { TimerId_MouseHover = 1 };
    static const UINT HoverTimeoutInMs = 1000;
    static int PrevX = INT_MIN;
    static int PrevY = INT_MIN;
    static bool IsMouseOutside = true;
    static bool IsMouseHovered = false;

    switch ( message ) {

    case WM_MOUSEMOVE: {
        // If mouse was previously outside, re-request WM_MOUSELEAVE messages
        if ( IsMouseOutside ) {
            TRACKMOUSEEVENT tme = { sizeof( tme ) };
            tme.dwFlags = TME_LEAVE;
            tme.hwndTrack = hWnd;
            ::TrackMouseEvent( &tme );
            IsMouseOutside = false;
        }

        int CurrX = GET_X_LPARAM( lParam );
        int CurrY = GET_Y_LPARAM( lParam );
        if ( ( CurrX != PrevX ) || ( CurrY != PrevY ) ) {
            // Mouse moved -> reset timer
            ::SetTimer( hWnd, TimerId_MouseHover, HoverTimeoutInMs, nullptr );
            PrevX = CurrX;
            PrevY = CurrY;
            IsMouseHovered = false;
            // For testing only:
            ::InvalidateRect( hWnd, nullptr, FALSE );
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Whenever the mouse leaves the client area we need to cancel the timer. If we didn't cancel the timer, it would expire, even when the mouse moves outside the window's client area:

```
    case WM_MOUSELEAVE:
        ::KillTimer( hWnd, TimerId_MouseHover );
        IsMouseOutside = true;
        PrevX = INT_MIN;
        PrevY = INT_MIN;
        return 0;
```

If our timer expires we have a hover event:

```
    case WM_TIMER:
        if ( wParam == TimerId_MouseHover ) {
            // The mouse hasn't been moved for the specified timeout:
            // This is a hover event
            IsMouseHovered = true;
            // For testing only:
            ::InvalidateRect( hWnd, nullptr, FALSE );
            return 0;
        }
        else {
            return ::DefWindowProc( hWnd, message, wParam, lParam );
        }
```

As a test, let's fill the client area with a black brush, whenever the hover timeout expires:

```
    case WM_PAINT: {
        PAINTSTRUCT ps;
        HDC hdc = BeginPaint( hWnd, &ps );
        ::FillRect( hdc, &ps.rcPaint, GetStockBrush( IsMouseHovered ? BLACK_BRUSH :
                                                                      WHITE_BRUSH ) );
        EndPaint( hWnd, &ps );
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Note that this reports when the mouse leaves a region (defined by `SPI_GETMOUSEHOVERWIDTH` and `SPI_GETMOUSEHOVERHEIGHT`), not a single pixel.